# different combinations of "$200" and "customs duty"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have made up the similar sentences below.

(1) I'm sad that I have to pay a $200 customs duty on my online order.

(2) I'm sad that I have to pay an customs duty of $200 on my online order.

(3) I'm sad that I have to pay $200 of customs duty on my online order.

(4) I'm sad that I have to pay $200 in customs duty on my online order.

I'm not sure about the correct way of saying "$200" and "customs duty" when they are put together. Please help me. Thanks very much.

Comment: (2) is ungrammatical, since you have used "AN" with customs. It should "A" customs duty...if it has to be.

Comment: to pay 200 dollars customs duty on my online order.